# Training Tagger with Custom Tags in NLTK

Tags: nlp, nltk, information-extraction, supervised-learning

I have a document with tagged data in the format `Hi here's my [KEYWORD phone number], let me know when you wanna hangout: [PHONE 7802708523]. I live in a [PROP_TYPE condo] in [CITY New York]`. I want to train a model based on a set of these type of tagged documents, and then use my model to tag new documents. Is this possible in NLTK? I have looked at [chunking](http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2000/chunking/) and [NLTK-Trainer](https://github.com/japerk/nltk-trainer) scripts, but these have a restricted set of tags and corpora, while my dataset has custom tags.

Comment: BIO chunk tags seems to be right direction, see http://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/10/14/coding-chunkers-as-taggers-io-bio-bmewo-and-bmewo/ . Depends on how you encode your input, you might need a fine-grain classifier to tag identify `PHONE` or `KEYWORD` after chunking.

Comment: Could you provide a few more examples? Are they all phone numbers? Maybe add [tag: information-extraction]?

Comment: No, the data is varied, it includes phone numbers, addresses, names, dates, etc. For BIO chunk tags, is there some code samples I can have a look at?

Answer (score 5):

As @AleksandarSavkov wrote already, this is essentially a named entity recognition (NER) task-- or more generally a chunking task, as you already realize. How to do it is covered nicely in [chapter 7](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) of the NLTK book. I recommend you ignore the sections on regexp tagging and use the approach in section 3, [Developing and evaluating chunkers](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#developing-and-evaluating-chunkers). It includes code samples you can use verbatim to create a chunker (the [`ConsecutiveNPChunkTagger`](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#code-classifier-chunker)). Your responsibility is to select features that will give you good performance.

You'll need to transform your data into the IOB format expected by the NLTK's architecture; it expects part of speech tags, so the first step should be to run your input through a POS tagger; `nltk.pos_tag()` will do a decent enough job (once you strip off markup like `[KEYWORD ...]`), and requires no additional software to be installed. When your corpus is in the following format (*word -- POS-tag -- IOB-tag*), you are ready to train a recognizer:

```
Hi NNP O
here RB O
's POS O
my PRP$ O
phone NN B-KEYWORD
number NN I-KEYWORD
, , O
let VB O
me PRP O
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm unclear about the step after running my input through the POS tagger. How do I insert my own custom tags? Maybe I misunderstood what you meant by stripping off markups like `KEYWORD`

Comment: I only just saw your comment... this response is almost as late as your comment itself, sorry! What I meant by "stripping off markup" is that the POS tagger works with tokenized plain text; you'll need to remove the chunk labels from your corpus, tokenize and tag the text with the NLTK, then insert the chunks again (which you might as well do in IOB format, since that's what you'll need in the end). If you still don't know how to do this, I can edit my answer to explain more.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. So the eventual output will be a list of `word POS-tag Custom-tag`, right?

Comment: You got it. With your "Custom-tags" expressed in IOB format. The example in my answer shows some of your sample text with the custom tag `KEYWORD`, translated to this format.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are looking to solve is called most commonly, [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) (NER). There are many algorithms that can help you solve the problem, but the most important notion is that you need to convert your text data into a suitable format for sequence taggers. Here is an example of the BIO format:

```
I     O
love  O
Paris B-LOC
and   O
New   B-LOC
York  I-LOC
.     O
```

From there, you can choose to train any type of classifier, such as Naive Bayes, SVM, MaxEnt, CRF, etc. Currently the most popular algorithm for such multi-token sequence classification tasks is [CRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field). There are available tools that will let you train a BIO model (although originally intended for chunking) from a file using the format shown above (e.g. [YamCha](http://chasen.org/~taku/software/yamcha/), [CRF++](https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/), [CRFSuite](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/), [Wapiti](https://wapiti.limsi.fr/)). If you are using Python you can look into [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/), [python-crfsuite](https://github.com/tpeng/python-crfsuite) and [PyStruct](https://pystruct.github.io/) in addition to NLTK.

Comment: The NLTK toolbox uses a three-column format: `word POS-tag BIO-tag`. It won't hurt to add a POS-tagging step to the processing pipeline.