# Giving your own custom tags to tokenize data in nltk?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy, pos-tagger

While running the below code

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk


sentence = "Antacids is given to Jhon,Sodium Bicarbonate is given to Carl,Folic Acid to Jeery  all works at Google " 
print(ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))))
```

i am getting this output

```
(S
  (GPE Antacids/NNP)
  is/VBZ
  given/VBN
  to/TO
  (PERSON Jhon/NNP)
  ,/,
  (PERSON Sodium/NNP Bicarbonate/NNP)
  is/VBZ
  given/VBN
  to/TO
  (GPE Carl/NNP)
  ,/,
  (PERSON Folic/NNP Acid/NNP)
  to/TO
  (GPE Jeery/NNP)
  all/DT
  works/NNS
  at/IN
  (ORGANIZATION Google/NNP))
```

I want to assign the medicines like (Antacid,Sodium, Folic) to same category.

Which library I can use for this purpose ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717131/training-tagger-with-custom-tags-in-nltk

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to keep some misspellings in your text? For example *Jhon* or *John*, *Jeery* or *Jerry*, upper case for common nouns (*Sodium Bicarbonate* 
 would be *sodium bicarbonate* with lower cases..)?

Embedded NER (Named Entity Recognition) in python libraries are trained with clean text, since you have a misspelled text it'll be hard to achieve 100% accuracy with a generic NER.

With a correct sentence and the `spacy` library you can get the correct output:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp("Antacids is given to John, sodium bicarbonate is given to Carl, folic acid to Jerry all works at Google")

for token in doc:
    print('token.i: {2}\ttoken.idx: {0}\ttoken.pos: {3:10}token.text: {1}'.
          format(token.idx, token.text, token.i, token.pos_)

print('Entities', [(e.text, e.label_) for e in doc.ents])
```

With the result (Antacids, sodium bicarbonate and acid are tagged as NOUN):

```
token.i: 0  token.idx: 0    token.pos: NOUN      token.text: Antacids
token.i: 1  token.idx: 9    token.pos: VERB      token.text: is
token.i: 2  token.idx: 12   token.pos: VERB      token.text: given
token.i: 3  token.idx: 18   token.pos: ADP       token.text: to
token.i: 4  token.idx: 21   token.pos: PROPN     token.text: John
token.i: 5  token.idx: 25   token.pos: PUNCT     token.text: ,
token.i: 6  token.idx: 27   token.pos: NOUN      token.text: sodium
token.i: 7  token.idx: 34   token.pos: NOUN      token.text: bicarbonate
token.i: 8  token.idx: 46   token.pos: VERB      token.text: is
token.i: 9  token.idx: 49   token.pos: VERB      token.text: given
token.i: 10 token.idx: 55   token.pos: ADP       token.text: to
token.i: 11 token.idx: 58   token.pos: PROPN     token.text: Carl
token.i: 12 token.idx: 62   token.pos: PUNCT     token.text: ,
token.i: 13 token.idx: 64   token.pos: ADJ       token.text: folic
token.i: 14 token.idx: 70   token.pos: NOUN      token.text: acid
token.i: 15 token.idx: 75   token.pos: ADP       token.text: to
token.i: 16 token.idx: 78   token.pos: PROPN     token.text: Jerry
token.i: 17 token.idx: 84   token.pos: DET       token.text: all
token.i: 18 token.idx: 88   token.pos: VERB      token.text: works
token.i: 19 token.idx: 94   token.pos: ADP       token.text: at
token.i: 20 token.idx: 97   token.pos: PROPN     token.text: Google
```

And the entities are correctly labeled:

```
Entities [('John', 'PERSON'), ('Carl', 'PERSON'), ('Jerry', 'PERSON'), ('Google', 'ORG')]
```

Comment: Is there any way to custom tag those medicines as med rather than noun??